# Adding Composite Geocoding Database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geolocation

I'm following an MIT tutorial I found here: https://libraries.mit.edu/files/gis/geocoding.pdf, to try to add a locator to ArcMap.

However, as I am not an MIT student, I cannot get to the step where I need to: "Download the ESRI data & maps data from IS&T."

I'm specifically looking for the "Street_Addresses_US" file to geolocate US addresses. I have access to ArcMap Desktop subscription, but cannot find access to these files.